# Using webjar and spring mvc, fonts in the css are not loaded

Tags: spring-mvc, fonts, webjars

For a brand new website, I am using Spring MVC and [the materialize webjar](http://www.webjars.org/listfiles/org.webjars.bower/materialize/0.97.0) :)
It works perfectly well, expect for the fonts :( They are not loaded!

1. In the Spring MVC application I've the following method which is reachable by `http://localhost/website/test`
2. When I load this page I see that fonts are not loaded : [image] (it is supposed to be an icon instead of *send*).
3. Materilize css file is loaded by the following import in a jsp page : `http://localhost:8180/webjars/materialize/0.97.0/bin/materialize.css`
4. So i think fonts are not loaded because of the link in [materialize.css](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/org.webjars.bower/materialize/0.97.0/bin/materialize.css) which is not root-based : `src: url("../font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.eot?#iefix")`. I guess, the application tries to load the file here : `http://localhost/website/font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.eot?#iefix` whereas it should load the file here : `http://localhost/webjars/materialize/0.97.0/font/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.ttf` (which is working when I test it manually)

I can't see any 404 errors in Network tab in chrome. So I don't know if the application even tries to loads the fonts.

I find a fix which consists in adding the following line in the head tag : `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`. In that case it works...

I can't figure out why fonts are not loaded with the webjar... Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to load the css from the dist dir instead:

```
http://localhost:8180/webjars/materialize/0.97.0/dist/css/materialize.css
```

Comment: Are you seeing web requests for the fonts in your network debugger?